# Exception using CuDF apply_chunks - Use of unsupported NumPy function 'numpy.ones_like' or unsupported use of the function

Tags: python, numpy, rapids, cudf

I am trying to use numpy from within jit optimized code of Numba but I am getting errors when I am trying to do standard numpy operations like numpy.ones_like, even though numba documentation mentions that the operation is supported.

Documentation link: [Numba 0.46](http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/0.46.0/reference/numpysupported.html).

Edit: The method 'calc_method' works fine if I make a direct call to it, fails when used from within apply_chunks. So probably not an issue with Numba itself but how cudf.apply_chunks is being used.

Code:

```
import numba
from numba import jit
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

print(numba.__version__)

@jit(nopython=True)
def calc_method(a,b):
    a1 = np.float64(a)
    b1 = np.float64(b)
    abc = (a1, np.ones_like(b1))
    abc_ht = np.hstack(abc)
    return abc_ht

def calculate(cudf_df: cudf, size_of_row: int):       
    return cudf_df.apply_chunks(calc_method, incols=['a', 'b'], outcols=dict(), chunks=size_of_row)

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], 'b': [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]})
cudf_df = cudf.DataFrame.from_pandas(df)
a, b = calculate(cudf_df, 4)
```

Error:

```
TypingError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-38-ad56fb75bc4a> in <module>
----> 1 a, b = calculate(cudf_df, 4)

TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
Invalid use of Function(<numba.cuda.compiler.DeviceFunctionTemplate object at 0x7fa78521b550>) with argument(s) of type(s): (array(int64, 1d, A), array(int64, 1d, A))
 * parameterized
In definition 0:
    TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
Use of unsupported NumPy function 'numpy.ones_like' or unsupported use of the function.

File "<ipython-input-37-97f7d707ba81>", line 9:
def calc_method(a,b):
    <source elided>
    b1 = np.float64(b)
    abc = (a1, np.ones_like(b1))
    ^
```

Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong in the above example? Thanks in advance.

I also get a similar error for np.hstack

Note: This is a simplified example to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Try removing the jit annotation, try replacing the pd.DataFrames with python lists. Keep simplifying it until it works.

Comment: `apply_chunks` is probably passing a dataframe or Series to your function.  `df.to_numpy()` is the preferred way of creating a numpy array from a dataframe.  That said, I too get an error with `hstack` using arrays.  That said, what do you hope to gain from `numba`?  You aren't iterating on anything.  `np.concatenate` is already compiled code.  So even if it works, `numba` might not save much time.

Comment: @hpaulj Good point, was just using this as a simplified example which reproduces the issue, the actual code has a lot more stuff going on. Will update the question with this note.

Comment: you might be interested in reading through this issue: https://github.com/dask/distributed/issues/3450 as it covers some recent issues of doing numba ufunc operations with dask

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use any numpy method that allocates memory from within a JIT kernel. Generally, you need to allocate your outputs ahead of time, and then set the values of those outputs in the kernel.

You can see an example of using `apply_chunks` here: https://gist.github.com/beckernick/acbfb9e8ac4f0657789930a0dfb57d17#file-udf_apply_chunks_basic_example-ipynb

Comment: While what you have mentioned makes sense, was just wondering why the official documentation mentions that 'ones_like' is supported, it always is going to allocate memory.

Comment: It may work in the non CUDA jit mode where memory allocations aren't nearly as expensive relative to the compute. If it doesn't work in a pure CPU mode I'd suggest raising an issue / PR on the Numba github about incorrect documentation.

Comment: I just checked, the function works with np.float64, np.ones_like and np.hstack, if I directly make a call to the 'calc_method' method. But doesn't work when the same method is called via cudf.apply_stack method. So I guess hstack does work in jit optimized code, as advertised. It's some combination of cudf.apply_chunks with jit optimized code that's causing the issue. 

@Keith: thanks for all the inputs, I'll reword the question a bit to highlight the cudf apply_chunks angle.